# OpenRewrite - recipe to change formatting of curly brackets

Tags: java, format, curly-braces, openrewrite

I started to playing with OpenRewrite and what I need is to use OpenRewrite to change the formatting of curly braces (for all the Java classes and interfaces).

So from this:

```
public class Foo
{
    // something here
}
```

to have this:

```
public class Foo { // <-- left curly bracket on the same line as a class name
    // something here
}
```

I was trying to achieve this with simple existing `org.openrewrite.java.format.AutoFormat` recipe, but it seems this one completely ignores the curly braces.
Then I tried to write some custom recipe and I was playing with method `autoFormat`. Something like this:

```
 @Override
 public J.ClassDeclaration visitClassDeclaration(final J.ClassDeclaration classDec, final ExecutionContext executionContext) {
     return autoFormat(classDec, executionContext);
 }
```

but it seems that `autoFormat` just uses `AutoFormatVisitor` and it seems to me that this one is also used by existing `org.openrewrite.java.format.AutoFormat` recipe - so it doesn't have the desired effect.

Could you please point me to some idea how this can be solved by OpenRewrite?

**UPDATE**
I tried to apply default IntelliJ style.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.44.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <activeRecipes>
            <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.format.AutoFormat</recipe>
        </activeRecipes>
        <activeStyles>
            <style>org.openrewrite.java.style.IntelliJ</style>
        </activeStyles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but it still didn't change the curly brackets.

Comment: Have you tried running https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/format/wrappingandbraces ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't have any effect.

Comment: There's also  been some feedback on our Slack: https://rewriteoss.slack.com/archives/C01A843MWG5/p1684417705241589

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to look into styles:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/concepts-explanations/styles

We support a range of well known styles already, such as for instance:
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/main/rewrite-java/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/java/style/IntelliJ.java

The Maven and Gradle plugins support passing in styles:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/rewrite-maven-plugin#plugin-configuration

```
./mvnw rewrite:run -Drewrite.activeStyles=an.example.Style0
```

This style should then be picked up by the code change or formatter recipes you apply.

Comment: I've already tried the style, see the updated question.

Comment: I also tried to do it via checkstyle - I mean I created a simple checkstyle.xml with desired curly bracket formatting and followed this: https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/popular-recipe-guides/automatically-fix-checkstyle-violations But still no luck.

Comment: Tyler helped to provide some context that I was missing in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76293036/53444 ; As also seen on the comment below his answer: feel free to open up a bug/feature request.

Answer (score 1):

So, the style classes in OpenRewrite are meant to closely support the configuration you see in Intellij:

[image]

However, in the case of [WrappingAndBracesStyle](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/main/rewrite-java/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/java/style/WrappingAndBracesStyle.java) there is currently a very minimally implementation. To add full support, this style class must be filled out (using the Intellij dialog as a guide) and then the [WrappingAndBracesVisitor](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/main/rewrite-java/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/java/format/WrappingAndBracesVisitor.java) needs to be implemented to use the styles to manipulate the whitespace of the various tree elements. Note that indention is handled by a different style/visitor and this visitor should focus specifically on removing/adding new lines.

Comment: Thank you for chiming in here Tyler! Guess that makes this a bug/feature request, with no current solution. @PetrS feel free to open up an issue over on https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues